# How to get entire HTML from HTMLFragment ( like innerHTML )

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have `fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()`
with some random Dom inside and I want to get the entire HTML ( excaly like `innerHTML` in regular element or `document.documentElement.innerHTML` in `document` object.

And after some text manipulation (by regex) return the HTML to the `fragment`
how can I do that ?

Comment: have you tryed something?

Comment: Add the fragment to a random node you create, get that nodes innerHTML. Alas the fragment object itsself doesnt support innerHTML, querySelector, etc. To re-add the updated html string, do the opposite. Add the string as innerHTML to a random node, then copy all childnodes to a new fragment.

Comment: I post my end up solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Copy Node to DocumentFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774889/javascript-copy-node-to-documentfragment)

Answer (score 3):

I end up with that ugly solution :

```
        var helperDiv = document.createElement('div');
        helperDiv.appendChild(fragment)
        var innerHTML = helperDiv.innerHTML.replace(someRegExp,()=>values())
        helperDiv.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        var len = helperDiv.children.length;
        while(len--){
            fragment.appendChild( helperDiv.firstChild );
        }
```

So I appreciated a better way

#### 2017 some update

I come with better solution with `Range`.

```
function fragmentInnerHTML(fragment, callback){
  var range = new Range();
  var helperDiv = document.createElement('div');
  helperDiv.appendChild(fragment);
  helperDiv.innerHTML = callback( helperDiv.innerHTML) 
  range.selectNodeContents(helperDiv);
  fragment.append( range.extractContents() );
  range.detach();
}

fragmentInnerHTML( fr, html => html.replace(/test(\d)/g,'test-$1') );
```

can be edited to be even fewer lines if needed

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vtssq8jz/26/

Comment: pery exciting to see I stumbled across your answer! haven't seen you since the days of the dorms!

Comment: nice :) I update the solution when you turn my attention to here :)

Answer (score 2):

If `f` is a documentFragment, its `innerHTML` can be retrieved using:

```
console.log([].map.call(f.children, e => e.outerHTML).join('\n'));
```

Note that `map` is not a method of `f.children`. As a result, the following code doesn't work:

```
console.log(f.children.map(e => e.outerHTML).join('\n'));
```

Comment: `console.log([...f.children].map(e => e.outerHTML).join('\n'));` does work however.

Comment: And, one doesn't necessarily need to join on newlines, it's possible to just do `.join('')`. It also makes much more sense since outerHTML is usually generated as a compact, unspaced string of HTML from the browser - i.e. it's not the original HTML the developer wrote that DID have spaces..

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon similar problem and see if this can help you:

```js
var $frag = new DocumentFragment();
var html = '' ; 
[].forEach.call($frag.children, function(el) { 
  html += el.outerHTML;
});
```

Basically iterate through the children property of document fragment and concatenate the outerHTMLs of its elements. :)

Comment: nice, it can be prettier by write : `[...$frag.children].map( e=> e.innerHTML ).join('↵')`

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this sort of problem previously, and I came to the conclusion that a document fragment is easier to work with when it has a single, top-level node. With that in mind, I would probably use a known 'container' element inside the document fragment, and then set and retrieve the innerHTML of that.

Something like this:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); //Initialise the fragment
fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('div')); //Create a top-level container element.
fragment.firstChild.innerHTML = 'Your chunk of DOM'; // Set the contents of your fragment, either with innerHTML, or by appending the child node.

console.log(fragment.firstChild.innerHTML); //Use any normal DOM node method to access the contents.
```

Basically you always use `fragment.firstChild` to access the contents of your fragment, so you have access to all of a DOM node's usual methods.

Comment: nice, but if you use the first `div` what the benefit you get from using `documentFragment`.  
I use it for the ability to contain sibling at the root . and add the entire siblings elements with simple `div.appendChild( fragment )`